# How to get array of similar texts from a source array against a keyword - PHP

Tags: php

Suppose I have keyword `Toy car` and array

```
$source_array = array(
    'Provision for toy that is a car',
    'Toy that looks like a car',
    'Toy Car',
    'Toy CAR'
);
```

I tried like

```
foreach($source_array as $v) {
    echo similar_text($key_word, $v);
}
```

It returns higher number for higher match. I need the result in array with higher match first.

Comment: What does similar_text function do?

Comment: @jerkan [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the results in an array, the key being the sentence and the value the score, then get the max score with the corresponding values :

```
$source_array = array(
    'Provision for toy that is a car',
    'Toy that looks like a car',
    'Toy Car',
    'Toy CAR',
    'Toy car'  // <----- I added a "perfect" match
);

$key_word = 'Toy car';
$result = [];
foreach($source_array as $v) {
    $result[$v] = similar_text($key_word, $v);
}

$highest_score = max($result);  // <--------------------- Get max score
$sentences = array_keys($result, $highest_score); // <--- Get the keys corresponding to that value

var_dump($sentences);
```

This outputs :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "Toy that looks like a car"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Toy car"
}
```

---

If all you want is sorting the results by highest match, you can use [arsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

```
$source_array = array(
    'Provision for toy that is a car',
    'Toy that looks like a car',
    'Toy Car',
    'Toy CAR',
    'Toy car'  // <----- I added a "perfect" match
);

$key_word = 'Toy car';
$result = [];
foreach($source_array as $v) {
    $result[$v] = similar_text($key_word, $v);
}

arsort($result);

var_dump($result);
```

---

```
array(5) {
  ["Toy that looks like a car"]=>
  int(7)
  ["Toy car"]=>
  int(7)
  ["Provision for toy that is a car"]=>
  int(6)
  ["Toy Car"]=>
  int(6)
  ["Toy CAR"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I already asked if I need all match I can use `$highest_score = krsort($result);`